# How to get link from elements with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Let's say, all Author/username elements in one webpage look like following...
How can I get to the `href` part using python and Selenium?

`users = browser.find_elements_by_xpath`(?)

```
<span>

    Author: 

    <a href="/account/57608-bob">

        bob

    </a>

</span>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `.//span[contains(text(), "Author")]/a` as xpath expression.

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://jsfiddle.net/9pKMU/show/')
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "Author")]/a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 23):

Use `find_elements_by_tag_name('a')` to find the 'a' tags, and then use `get_attribute('href')` to get the link string.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to parse through all of the links on the page then to find ones that contain "account"? How can I find ones that are just in a span element with Author: ?

Comment: @jacob501 Ah, I missed the condition. If you want to find the "account" links, beautifulsoup is very helpful to do such jobs. You may use it like this: `soup.findAll('span', text=re.compile(r'Author:')` to find the target "span" and then `find('a').attrs['href']` to get the link. It's more readable.

Comment: Ah, I forget something, beautifulsoup is only for page parse, if you want to do some actions in selenium, falsetru's answer is better.

Comment: `URL = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')` is how you return this as a string.

Answer (score 1):

**Using this code you can get the all links from a webpage**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://your website/")
# identify elements with tagname <a>
lnks=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
# traverse list
for lnk in lnks:
   # get_attribute() to get all href
   print(lnk.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```