# How to get links of elements filtering with more keywords with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

From reference to this, [How to get link from elements with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850539/how-to-get-link-from-elements-with-selenium-and-python/20850600)

I tried:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "SPE8ED-21-Q-1288")]/a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

This showed the results as:

```
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Default.aspx
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Solicitations/Default.aspx
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/Default.aspx
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RFQNsn.aspx?value=8145014862449&category=post&Scope=
https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE8ED21Q1288.PDF
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/rfq/rfqrec.aspx?sn=SPE8ED21Q1288
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RA/Quote/QuoteFrm.aspx?sn=SPE8ED21Q1288
```

I am interested in getting only the link that contains `Downloads` keyword only.

In this case,

```
https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE8ED21Q1288.PDF
```

Any idea to do this filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **filter** **Downloads** keyword like this.

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "SPE8ED-21-Q-1288")]/a'):
    if "Downloads" in a.get_attribute('href'):
        print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

**Code Explanation :**

we are getting a `list of web elements` and then looking (by **iterating**) for each and **every web element** for their attribute `href` ,if `Downloads` is found then print the `href`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "SPE8ED-21-Q-1288")]/a'):
    if "Downloads" in a.get_attribute("href"):
        print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```